# android Toast doesn't apprear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i have a xml file with textview that contains a drawabletop image and customize listview that contains a header, i want when clicking the textview to show a toast, i don't know why nothing is apprear

## Java Activity

i have a xml file with textview that contains a drawabletop image and customize listview that contains a header, i want when clicking the textview to show a toast, i don't know why nothing is apprear

## Java Activity

```
tv_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_myID);
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.myID:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have created a Toast but you have to call show() to show toast. Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: you are missing **.show()** here change it to Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: **.show()** is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this `tv_title.setOnClickListener(this);` after the this

```
tv_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurant_description_title);
```

Comment: @FernadoMargin : but you need to make TextView click able

Comment: Waoooo you up-voted those answers which didn't work for you... and which work you didn't upvoted....

Comment: @PankajKumar i forget to upvote, sorry , i will accept in after 10mins

Answer (score 2):

channe to this    `Toast.makeText(this, "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: still nothing appear, and in all the tutorials that i have seen, they don't use `.show()`, check this out http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your code:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

to

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget to call `Toast.show()` method to show Toast on Button Click change it as :

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```